# Calculating the number of occurrences for each possible combination in a n-card hand

Tags: python-3.x

I want to list out all possible combination of a n-card poker hand that a player can get, along with the point total, and the number of occurrences for each combination in which the order and suit does not matter [i.e., combination question]

As illustrated in the picture below, for a 2-card poker hand, I will have:
Column A: Picture, which tells me if it is a face card of J, Q or K
Column B: 1st card
Column C: 2nd card
Column D: Points Total of 1st card + 2nd card
Column E: # of occurrences

In this case the points total for a 2-card hand ranges from 2 (1+1) to 21.

For a 3-card poker hand, I will have an additional column for the 3rd card:
Column A: Picture, which tells me if it is a face card of J, Q or K
Column B: 1st card
Column C: 2nd card
Column D: 3rd card
Column E: Points Total of 1st card + 2nd card + 3rd card
Column F: # of occurrences

[Excel illustration of 2 card hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XA2m.png)

Additionally, I want to have 2 inputs:

1. Number of cards per hand, i.e., n
2. Number of decks of cards

Furthermore, "A" can be used as both 1 and 11.

I tried my hands on this problem but I am stuck with how to edit my code to the requirements:

```
''' Get user input for # of cards each hand, and the number of decks'''
no_of_cards = int(input("How many cards per hand?"))
no_of_decks = input("How many decks of cards?")

def generate_poker_combinations(no_of_cards):
    suits = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades']
    ranks = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']

    # Create a standard deck of 52 cards
    deck = list(itertools.product(ranks, suits))

    # Generate all combinations of n-card hands
    combinations = list(itertools.combinations(deck, no_of_cards))

    return combinations

def count_combination_occurrences(combinations, hand):
    count = combinations.count(hand)
    return count

all_combinations = generate_poker_combinations(no_of_cards)

for combination in all_combinations:
    occurrences = count_combination_occurrences(all_combinations, combination)
    print(f"{combination}: {occurrences} occurrences")
```

Would appreciate any help!!!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.